# Python Time zone: get abbreviation and UTC offset

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone, pytz

my time zone is "Australia/Melbourne" (I have multiple zones like this when I give this to my function) and  I need the output like this ASET(GMT +10). How can I reach my answer?

Thank you

Comment: If you have tz with/without DST, the UTC offset will depend on the date/time. Is that available to your function?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62699376/10197418

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assuming you have date and time available (see my comment), the easiest way is probably `strftime`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz

timezone = tz.gettz("Australia/Melbourne")
dt = datetime.now(timezone)

print(f"{dt.strftime('%Z')}(GMT{dt.strftime('%z')})")
# AEST(GMT+1000)
```

If you exactly want to get the specified output, I suppose you have to go a little more sophisticated:

```
total_minutes, seconds = divmod(dt.utcoffset().total_seconds(), 60)
hours, minutes = divmod(total_minutes, 60)
utcoff = f"{int(hours):+d}:{int(minutes):02d}" if minutes else f"{int(hours):+d}"
    
print(f"{dt.strftime('%Z')}(GMT{utcoff})")
# AEST(GMT+10)
```