# Get local timezone as letter code in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I typically use this code to obtain local timezone:

```py
import platform
import time
import datetime
import pytz

#LOCAL_TIMEZONE = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone().tzinfo # "CEST", etc on Linux, but 'Romance Standard Time' on Windows
if "win" in platform.system().lower(): # SO:1387222
  # SO:16156597 - try tzlocal.win32; MINGW64: `pip3.8.exe install tzlocal`; RPi: `sudo apt install python3-tzlocal`
  from tzlocal.win32 import get_localzone_name
  LOCAL_TIMEZONE = pytz.timezone(get_localzone_name())
else:
  from tzlocal import get_localzone
  LOCAL_TIMEZONE = get_localzone()
# Above results with LOCAL_TIMEZONE: Europe/Copenhagen in Linux, Europe/Paris in Windows
```

How can I obtain the local timezone as CET or CEST (letter code) that works in both Windows and Linux?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62669675/python-time-zone/62670659#62670659

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the [`tzlocal`](https://github.com/regebro/tzlocal) package should provide you with what you need - however you also need a `datetime` object that you can use for `strftime('%Z')`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from tzlocal import get_localzone

print(datetime.now(tz=get_localzone()).strftime('%Z'))
# CEST
```

p.s. I'm on Windows; can't test right now on Linux.

Comment: Perfect, thanks - works on both Windows and Raspberry Pi Raspbian